# How to calculate the division of two SELECTs in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, select, syntax

I would like to calculate the division of two rowcounts, so something like this:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col_name > crit) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)
```

However, this creates a syntax error when I tried it.

How can I realize what I want?

Comment: Later x-post on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78079765/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT AVG((col_name > crit)::INT) FROM table
```

> this creates a syntax error when I tried it

Your expression does not contain outer SELECT. To make it correct you'd write

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE col_name > crit) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table)
```

Answer (score 4):

Of course, while both counts are based on the same table(s), you would do that in a *single* `SELECT`, which is typically much cheaper. Use the aggregate `FILTER` clause. See:

- [Aggregate columns with additional (distinct) filters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27141193/939860)

And throw in [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to defend against division by zero:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE col_name > crit) / NULLIF(count(*), 0)
FROM   tbl;
```